# fetching yahoo contacts in iphone

Tags: ios, yahoo-api

I am following this link: https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-objc for retrieving yahoo contacts.

After providing all the credentials (i.e secret key, consumer key, app id) it is going to browser for login. But after logged in, it's displaying this message:

> To complete sharing of yahoo! info with xxxx, enter code xxxx into xxxx

So, I am not getting that where I should enter this code? And how will it redirect to my application.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[CloudSponge](http://www.cloudsponge.com) has an iOS widget for its contact importer.  Visit [our test drive page](http://www.cloudsponge.com/test-drive) from your iOS device to see how it works.

I work for CloudSponge, please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks @Jay, I see that your app works, but how are you doing that extra window, what is happening behind the scenes there?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your callback url. By default it's "oob" and will give you the verifier code. It will be better if you present your own web view and monitor the verifier code through webview delegates. Here's how you do it.

```
YOSSession *yahooSession; //instance variable

- (IBAction)yahooButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    yahooSession = [YOSSession sessionWithConsumerKey:YAHOO_CONSUMER_KEY
                                           andConsumerSecret:YAHOO_CONSUMER_SECRET
                                            andApplicationId:YAHOO_APP_ID];

    // try to resume a user session if one exists
    BOOL hasSession = [yahooSession resumeSession];

    if(hasSession == FALSE) {
        [self fetchSession];
    }else{
        [self sendRequests];
    }
}

-(void)fetchSession{

    // create a new YOSAuthRequest used to fetch OAuth tokens.
    YOSAuthRequest *tokenAuthRequest = [YOSAuthRequest requestWithSession:yahooSession];

    // fetch a new request token from oauth.
    YOSRequestToken *newRequestToken = [tokenAuthRequest fetchRequestTokenWithCallbackUrl:@"http://localhost"];

    // if it looks like we have a valid request token
    if(newRequestToken && newRequestToken.key && newRequestToken.secret) {
        // store the request token for later use
        [yahooSession setRequestToken:newRequestToken];
        [yahooSession saveSession];

        // create an authorization URL for the request token
        NSURL *authorizationUrl = [tokenAuthRequest authUrlForRequestToken:yahooSession.requestToken];
        [self presentWebViewForYahooWithAuthURL:authorizationUrl];
        //present it in webview

    } else {
        // NSLog(@"error fetching request token. check your consumer key and secret.");
    }
}

-(void) presentWebViewForYahooWithAuthURL:(NSURL *)url{

    _yahooWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    _yahooWebView.delegate=self; //so that we can observe the url for verifier
    [_yahooWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    [self.view addSubview:_yahooWebView];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    NSString *requestString = request.URL.absoluteString;
    if ([requestString rangeOfString:@"http://localhost"].length>0) {
        NSRange verifierRange = [requestString rangeOfString:@"oauth_verifier="];
        if (verifierRange.length>0) {

            verifierRange.location =verifierRange.location+verifierRange.length;
            verifierRange.length = requestString.length-verifierRange.location;
            NSLog(@"Verifier => %@", [requestString substringWithRange:verifierRange]);
            yahooSession.verifier=[requestString substringWithRange:verifierRange];
            [self sendRequests];
        }
        return NO;
    }
    else{
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @AdityaSinha, have you successfully worked with yahoo. I want to fetch yahoo user contacts. For first time app is crashes. When i try with next time. The app is working and yahoo contact also fetched. But i want to find out that what problem with yahoo sdk. Please provide full code if possible.

Comment: i'm also confused `ApplicationId` parameter. what is the value of application id when initalizing `YOSSession`.

Comment: and also please provide knowledge of callbackurl. I'm understanding that the call back url is use for app redirection. and that is we will write in .plist. like myApp://   But when we create new app in YDN this is ask for Callback url (like facebook) and this is not accepting any kind of string which are not starting from http or https.

Comment: @ChetanPrajapati Same problem with me, i am stuck of this. Did you find the solution? please suggest me

Comment: I had skipped this functionality.